# JQuery-UI Droppable widget: function is not running after appendTo

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have some draggable boxes and a droppable target. When a draggable element is dropped on `.output`, I want to console.log("SORTABLE").

This code works up to appendTo($(this) (the draggable target is detached from it's origin and appended to `.output`), but the console log doesn't run:

```
$( ".output" ).droppable({
    hoverClass: "active",
    drop:function(event, ui) {
        console.log("DROPPED")
        ui.draggable.detach().appendTo($(this), function() {
           console.log("SORTABLE")
        });

    }
});
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong- what's the correct way to declare a function here?

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly what you want to do is remove the element from its original position after drop is that so ? Then what you have to do is define it on the draggable options.

```
.draggable({
    connectToSortable: ".output",
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid"
});
```

hope this helped.